# issue while accessing global func in app delegate

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, appdelegate

I am new to swift and i created one swift file with name `mySession` and in that file i am storing login data like below

**Store Login Data**

```
 func setLoginData (data:Data) {
        let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
        let Key_Login = "Login"

        preferences.set(data, forKey: Key_Login)
        preferences.synchronize()
    }
```

and second func for use that stored data

**Get Data**

```
func getLoginData ()->Data {
        let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
        let Key_Login = "Login"

        if preferences.object(forKey: Key_Login) == nil {
            return data
        } else {
            return preferences.data(forKey: Key_Login)!
        }
    }
```

So now my question is that i want to use getLoginData func in my app delegate to check user is logged in or not so not able to under stand how to use that func in app delegate

Comment: What issue are you facing? Did you try calling the function and got some errors?

Comment: import that class, create the instance of that class and just call the function.

Comment: what is data in your example ?

Comment: i do one thing i create one var and assign my class to variable like this var mySessionClass = SomeClass() in my app delegate but still i am not getting my func and i am new here so not idea exactly whats the issue is so please help me

Comment: @AbuUlHassan io don't used data anywhere its written by mistake

Comment: then edit your question for mistakes and let us help you :) .

Comment: @AbuUlHassan thanks for replying but SirCj answer is solve my problem

Comment: okay no problem.

Comment: I think you say "global func" in your title. If these func are written in global, you should be able to call them directly without any prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encapsulate these methods inside a class and use an instance of that class inside `AppDelegate`

```
class MySession { 

 func setLogin(_ data: Data){...}

 func getLoginData() -> Data {...}


}
```

At the call site, instantiate `MySession` and use your methods to do what's needed.

```
class AppDelegate { 
//...
let sessionHandler = MySession()
sessionHandler.getLoginData()

 }
```

Sidenote, make sure you're using proper Swift 4 naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

First Import the file name in `AppDelegate`

```
Import mySession
```

Then just call the method in your desired function.

```
    setLoginData(data:<your Data>)
```

For example.If you want to use it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, follow this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    DefaultNetworkManager.appsConfigSetup()

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    setupApplication()

    setLoginData(data: <Your Data>)

    return true
}
```

Comment: Welcome @Vishal, Have a great Day!